# How can I edit or remove a FirebaseAuth user's phone or email? What happens with their old login credentials after they switch?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app with Flutter that allows the user to edit their login credentials, but the documentation on FirebaseAuth on what happens is very limited, and as I discovered it differs between phone and email.

Below I've outlined my experimental findings about what happens when editing email or when editing phone related to Firebase Auth, and how providerData is structured - parts which would be helpful to be in the Firebase Auth documentation but aren't (if any Firebase devs are reading this, feel free to copy what I wrote to improve the documentation)

What I am curious about (and couldn't find) is how I can remove an email from an account that has both email and phone - so that I can only log in with my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: After a discussion with @Alex Mamo I understood the following:

1. If the phone account is linked to an email through a password-based login (providerId=`password`), then calling unlink, would result in an account with only phone again (the user CANNOT login with the email anymore)
2. If the phone account is linked to an email through Google (an external service, providerId=`google.com`), then calling unlink would not remove the email (the user CAN login with the email still)

---

So I did some experiments and I'm sharing the results hoping to help someone (because if I had this info it would've saved me a lot of time and frustration).

Especially editing an email behaves in rather unexpected ways.

I experimented with 3 scenarios: phone login, Google login and passwordless login. A FirebaseAuth User object has two relevant fields for access rights: the `providerData` and `userInfo`.

## 1. Phone login

```
[{
email: null
isEmailVerified: true
phoneNumber: "+1 123-456-7890"
providerId: "phone"
uid: "+1 123-456-7890"
...
}]
```

userInfo:

```
email: null
isEmailVerified: false
phoneNumber: "+1 123-456-7890"
providerId: null
uid: "uid1"
...
```

### 1.1 Unlink phone

For the User object `user` calling `user.unlink("phone")`
→ Wipes providerData and modifies userInfo - removing phoneNumber
→ Can no longer login with +1 123-456-7890

### 1.2 Edit phone

For the User object `user` calling `user.linkWithCredential(credential)`
→ Replaces providerData with new the phone and modifies userInfo to the new phoneNumber
→ Can no longer login with +1 123-456-7890 and can login with the new one

## 2. Email login

providerData:

```
[{
email: "Aexample@gmail.com"
isEmailVerified: true
phoneNumber: null
providerId: "google.com"
uid: "71593587134053905"
...
}]
```

userInfo:

```
email: "Aexample@gmail.com"
isEmailVerified: true
phoneNumber: null
providerId: null
uid: "uidmail1"
...
```

### 2.1 Unlink email

For the User object `user` calling `user.unlink("google.com")`
→ Wipes providerData without modifying userInfo. So I can still log in with the email

### 2.2 Edit email

Sending a verification email and applying the action code.
→ When the verification email is sent, nothing is changed about the FirebaseAuth User
→ After changing to `Bexample@gmail.com`:

#### 2.2.1 I can still log in with the old email

→ I can still login with `Aexample@gmail.com` 
→ If I haven't logged in with `Bexample@gmail.com` yet, then providerData only contains `Aexample@gmail.com` even though userInfo contains `Bexample@gmail.com`
→ Only if I log in with `Bexample@gmail.com` does it get added to providerData and then it contains two items:

```
[{
email: "Aexample@gmail.com"
isEmailVerified: true
phoneNumber: null
providerId: "google.com"
uid: "71593587134053905"
},{
email: "Bexample@gmail.com"
isEmailVerified: true
phoneNumber: null
providerId: "google.com"
uid: "90839670913908504"
...
}]
```

#### 2.2.2 I can assign the old email to another account

→ So, if another account with phone only links to email "Aexample@gmail.com", then FirebaseAuth has two users connected with the email. However, when logging in with "Aexample@gmail.com" I still get logged in as the old account (which now has userInfo email "Bexample@gmail.com")

#### 2.2.3 Unlink again

→ Wipes the providerData and the userInfo stays the same as before
→ Now "Aexample@gmail.com" is no longer associated in any way with the old account and logging in opens the new account

## 3. Passwordless login

Unlink wipes the providerData, userInfo stays the same as before, so I can login with the email again

Answer (score 0):

> The documentation on FirebaseAuth on what happens is very limited, and as I discovered it differs between phone and email.

Yes, that is correct. Firebase authentication with email and password is different than the Firebase authentication with phone number. So if a user signs in with email and password and right after that with the phone number, then two separate accounts will be created, one with email and password and one with the phone number.

> What I am curious about (and couldn't find) is how I can remove an email from an account that has both email and phone - so that I can only log in with a phone number.

As far as I understand, you already [linked the account with email and password and the one with phone number into a single account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking). If so, if you want to [unlink an account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#unlink-an-auth-provider-from-a-user-account) then you have to call [FirebaseUser#unlink()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#unlink(java.lang.String)) method and specify the provider.

Comment: Hey Alex, as I've outlined in my experiment, calling `FirebaseUser#unlink("google.com")` doesn't stop me from logging into that account with my email. So once I've linked an account with email and with phone into a single account, I can remove the phone using `unlink("phone")` but not the email

Comment: What do you mean by "logging into that account with my email"? Are you referring to using email and password?

Comment: No, I mean using the Google authentication. What happens for you when you execute the following steps:
1. Create an account with gmail

2. Log in using google sign in (you can use https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)

3. Call FirebaseUser#unlink("google.com")

4. Log out and log in again...

Comment: You'll have to use the account that was previously linked.

Comment: Yes. But then what's the point of unlink if I can still log in with the same email into the same account?

With phone, when unlink is called, the phone number is disconnected from the account

Comment: You can still log in because you have used the same email address. But keep in mind that Firebase authentication with email and password is totally different than Firebase authentication with a provider like Google. In the first case, you get user input and create an account, while when using Google you're using Google credentials which are securely stored in Google account. If you don't want such behavior, then you can entirely delete the account from Firebase Authentication without unliking the account. Is it clear now?

Comment: Well, entirely deleting the account from Firebase Auth would also not allow logging into that account with a phone number anymore. So after this discussion, the TL;DR, from what I understood, is "No, it is NOT possible to remove an email from an account that has both email and phone connected, so that you can only login with the phone"

Comment: If you sign in the first time with a phone, and then you link the account with email and password, when unlink the account, you get back to the initial account.